# How to stop CFSocket from sending callbacks?

Tags: macos, cocoa, callback, invalidation, cfsocket

I have a server app which creates an object for every client that connects. In this object's `init` method I use this code to create a `CFSocket` to communicate with the client:

```
CFSocketContext context = {
    .info = self
};

socket = CFSocketCreateWithNative( kCFAllocatorDefault, nativeSocket, kCFSocketDataCallBack, SocketCallback, &context );
source = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource( kCFAllocatorDefault, socket, 0 );
CFRunLoopAddSource( CFRunLoopGetMain(), source, kCFRunLoopCommonModes );
```

When the main program is done with the client it releases the `ClientConnection` object and it's `dealloc` method gets called:

```
CFSocketDisableCallBacks( socket, kCFSocketDataCallBack );

CFRunLoopRemoveSource( CFRunLoopGetMain(), source, kCFRunLoopCommonModes );
CFRelease( source );

CFSocketInvalidate( socket );
CFRelease( socket );
```

After that is done I still receive data callbacks which get routed to the now deallocated object which causes a crash.

I tried everything I can think off, but I still can't make this work. Any ideas about why the `CFSocket` is sending callbacks after it has been invalidated?

Comment: Solved this problem. Without realizing it I was calling the release (and thus the dealloc) from inside the callback handler. Turns out that CFSocket doesn't like that.

Answer (score 1):

Some `CFSocket` callbacks may be automatically reenabled after you have disabled them, notably `kCFSocketDataCallBack`. It seems likely that the callbacks are being used between the time you made the disable call, and when the socket was invalidated.

To prevent this behaviour, you need to disable them with `CFSocketSetSocketFlags`:

```
CFOptionFlags sockopt = CFSocketGetSocketFlags (mysock);
sockopt &= kCFSocketDataCallBack;
CFSocketSetSocketFlags(s, sockopt);
```

Comment: Good information, but this was not the problem. Turns out CFSocket doesn't like to be invalidated from inside a callback handler.